# Upload image from J2ME client to a Servlet

Tags: java, image, servlets, java-me

I want to send an image from a J2ME client to a Servlet.

I am able to get a byte array of the image and send it using HTTP POST.

```
conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url, Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
os.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length); // bytes = byte array of image
```

This is the Servlet code:

```
String line;
BufferedReader r1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
while ((line = r1.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("line=" + line);
    buf.append(line);
}
String s = buf.toString();
byte[] img_byte = s.getBytes();
```

But the problem I found is, when I send bytes from the J2ME client, some bytes are lost. Their values are `0A` and `0D` hex. Exactly, the Carriage Return and Line Feed.

Thus, either POST method or `readLine()` are not able to accept `0A` and `0D` values.

Any one have any idea how to do this, or how to use any another method?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using a `BufferedReader` to read the binary stream **line by line**. The `readLine()` basically *splits* the content on CRLF. Those individual lines doesn't contain the CRLF anymore.

Don't use the `BufferedReader` for binary streams, it doesn't make sense. Just write the obtained `InputStream` to an `OutputStream` of any flavor, e.g. `FileOutputStream`, the [usual Java IO way](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/).

```
InputStream input = null;
OutputStream output = null;

try {
    input = request.getInputStream();
    output = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/file.ext");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
    for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer()) > 0;) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
} finally {
    if (output != null) output.close();
    if (input != null) input.close();
}
```

---

That said, the `Content-Type` you're using is technically wrong. You aren't sending a WWW-form URL-encoded value in the request body. You are sending a binary stream. It should be `application/octet-stream` or maybe `image`. This is not the cause of this problem, but it is just plain wrong.